# Is there any way to get a DetailsView control to render its HeaderText in a <th> cell?

Tags: asp.net

As the DetailsView uses <td> cells for both the header text and the data, I was wondering whether the behaviour of the control can be overridden to render the HeaderText of each row in a <th> cell?

---

@Joel Coehoorn Thanks for the quick reply, but I was kind of hoping I wouldn't have to go down that route.

I was wondering whether it would be possible to override one of the control rendering methods to achieve this?

Someone seems to have [had success rendering <th> cells](http://forums.asp.net/p/985785/1270559.aspx) but did not appear to disclose details - any other suggestions would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find a way around this by using the ItemCreaed event handler and swapping the <td> cell for a <th> cell like this:

```
if (view.Rows.Count > 0) {
    // swap each header <td> cell for a <th> cell
    foreach (DetailsViewRow row in view.Rows) {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
            DataControlFieldCell td = row.Cells[0] as DataControlFieldCell;
            // skip the last row that contains our command controls
            if (td.Controls.Count > 0) {
                continue;
            }

            DataControlFieldHeaderCell th = new DataControlFieldHeaderCell(td.ContainingField);
            th.Text = td.Text;
            th.Attributes.Add("scope", "row");

            // add the new th and remove the old td
            row.Cells.RemoveAt(0);
            row.Cells.AddAt(0, th);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no option built into the control itself.  However, you can completely override the render behavior for any control, including DetailsView, by using a [Control Adapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.adapters.controladapter.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You could also inherit your own custom control from DetailsView, and then override the render method.

Answer (score 0):

inherit from DetailsView and paste the code.
this eliminate the need to recreate the header cell (as suggested in Ian's answer)

```
protected override void InitializeRow(DetailsViewRow row, DataControlField field)
{
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && field.ShowHeader)
        {
            DataControlFieldCell cell = new DataControlFieldHeaderCell(field);
            field.InitializeCell(cell, DataControlCellType.Header, row.RowState, DataItemIndex);
            row.Cells.Add(cell);
            cell = new DataControlFieldCell(field);
            field.InitializeCell(cell, DataControlCellType.DataCell, row.RowState, DataItemIndex);
            row.Cells.Add(cell);
        }
        else base.InitializeRow(row, field);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).